# Partitioned Batch Job Message Aggregation Problems

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

We are running a bunch of partitioned jobs. Occasionally, a job will get "stuck" and not complete. I turned up the logging and see the log statements for sending the messages and obtaining a reply. I see the same number of both (and matching our grid sizes) but do not see the step complete.

```
2016-12-19 19:00:12,323 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer] (org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway#0.replyListener-1) Rec
eived message of type [class org.jboss.jms.message.ObjectMessageProxy] from consumer [JBossMessageConsumer->ConsumerDelegate[963904217, ID=4d7h-x6nuqwwi-1-3aky9qwi-thplfd-dx1m4a]] of session [JBo
ssSession->SessionDelegate[1869025798, ID=3d7h-x6nuqwwi-1-3aky9qwi-thplfd-dx1m4a]]

2016-12-19 19:00:12,323 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway] (org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway#0.replyListener-1) Received reply with correlationId 52e7a2fe-5f27-43e2-877e-d51383059dfa_23

2016-12-19 19:00:12,323 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway] (springbatch.partitioned.jms.taskExecutor-12) xx.outbound-gateway Obtained reply with CorrelationId 52e7a2fe-5f27-43e2-877e-d51383059dfa_23

2016-12-19 19:00:12,338 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway] (springbatch.partitioned.jms.taskExecutor-12) converted JMS Message [delegator->JBossMessage[150186246558120156]:PERSISTENT, deliveryId=41] to integration Message payload [StepExecution: id=66106, version=3, name=xx.partitioned.loadStagingtoPc:3, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=1, filterCount=0, writeCount=1 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=]

2016-12-19 19:00:12,338 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway] (springbatch.partitioned.jms.taskExecutor-12) handler 'org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway#0' sending reply Message: [Payload=StepExecution: id=66106, version=3, name=xx.partitioned.loadStagingtoPc:3, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=1, filterCount=0, writeCount=1 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=][Headers={timestamp=1482192012338, id=569a87fd-3f2f-40b8-bf47-3ac4d1b9fe0e, jms_timestamp=1482192012270, replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel@154c762, correlationId=7923:xx.partitioned.loadStagingtoPc, jms_redelivered=false, sequenceSize=50, jms_replyTo=JBossTopic[partitionReplyTopic], sequenceNumber=11, jms_messageId=ID:JBM-cc4fc0df-3a08-4509-80f1-435454f911af}]
```

I see these log statements for all of the messages.

What is the best way to debug the message aggregation processing?

I can't find a class with a log statement that will show that is happening. (Spring Batch 2.2.7)

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand the question `sequenceSize=50` indicates there are 50 partitions, `sequenceNumber=11` is the 11th partition. The aggregator uses a simple `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` - i.e. the group is released when all 50 partitions in group `7923:xx.partitioned.loadStagingtoPc` complete.

Comment: For the vast majority of the time, everything works fine. However occasionally on a later run of some of the jobs they do not complete. The remote partitioned steps are all COMPLETE, we see the messages received by the partition step master but it stays in STARTED. So I was looking for possible causes and how to debug. 

Is there any way a message from a previous run be part of the problem ? How are the messages that were received reset with ech run of the job?

Comment: The `correlationId` is unique for each job execution (the 7923 in this case is the job execution id): `setCorrelationId(stepExecutionRequest.getJobExecutionId() + ":" + stepExecutionRequest.getStepName())`. The only way a step will not complete is if some partition execution result went astray. Spring Batch 3.0 added an alternative step completion strategy (poll the job repository for partition completion rather than using the reply messages).